# Regex: Select links containing space

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I want to find all links containing a space before extension `.html`

`bla blah THIS-IS-MY-LINK .html blah blah`

I made a regex, but is not quite good, because it selects everything before my link, not just my link:

`.*(\w+( .html))`

Can anyone help me a little bit?

Comment: Try `\S+\s*\.html`. How can you identify the starting boundary of the link? If it starts with `http`, I'd rather use `http://\S*\s*\.html`. Or, if there can be several spaces, `http://.*?(?=\.html|$)`

Comment: No, sorry, is not good. Your regex will select also the links without space before.html, so I need to match only those links that contains a space before .html

Comment: Ok, so `\S+\h+\.html`? If a line break can be there, `\S+\s+\.html` might work better.

Comment: yes, your first regex needed a space:  `\S+\s* \.html` And also the second is very good. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there must be a *regular space* between 1+ non-whitespace characters and a `.html`, you may use

```
\S+ \.html
```

**Details**:

- `\S+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace
- - a space (if you may have any whitespace here, replace with `\s`, and if there can be any *horizontal* whitespace, replace with `\h`)
- `\.html` - a `.html` substring.
  [image]